# Camping near a beach, not far from Tokyo

Tags: camping, beaches, japan, tokyo

I am looking for a place to [camp](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sleep#Camping) (tent, coming by bicycle or train), at walking distance from a beach, and not far from [Tokyo](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo).

Any recommendation?

I have found a few lists of camping addresses, but no reasonably exhaustive map.
There are lists in PDF format, but it is really hard to estimate location from that.
The ideal would be a Google-Maps-based mashup showing all campings, if that exists?

Comment: All the beach areas vaguely near Tokyo that I have seen are extremely built up. Including freeways over the water itself. I would be very interested to know if there are campgrounds though.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard of people camping on the beach at Enoshima, but I don't think it's an official campground. Enoshima is about 1:30 from Tokyo and the station is a block or two from the beach.

Comment: You'll recognize it by the surfboards and the freeways built over the water (-; I'll see if I can get some of my Japanese friends to look at this question...